# select data from related tables and display their counts in the relating table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a table which stores data about an inspection. Inspections are carried out in a particular company belonging to an industry, located in a region. the inspections table has the industry_id field referencing the industry table and the region_id field referencing the region table.

Both industry and region tables have id and name fields.

running this query:

```
SELECT i.name industry, r.name region, COUNT(*) 
FROM labour_inspections l
left join company_industries i on l.industry_id=i.id 
left join regions r on l.region_id=r.id 
where i.name != 'NULL' and r.name != 'NULL' 
GROUP BY i.name and r.name
```

gives me the results i need but not in the way i want it for this view.[image: Desired report view]

I achieved that by writing separate queries and putting the results together with PHP. It is not elegant and I am concerned about performance.

Is there a way I can achieve the view in the image with a single query? Thank you all in advance

Comment: Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` and remove the whole `WHERE` clause.

Comment: *Is there a way I can achieve the view in the image with a single query?* MySQL knows nothing about PIVOT. Transform your data on the client side (using its report component, for example) or emulate pivot with a code in a stored procedure form (you must understand it is not easy to create such procedure).

Answer (score 0):

```
name != 'NULL'
```

That assumes that `name` can be the 4-letter string 'NULL'.  If, in reality, it can be the special value `NULL`, then do this:

```
name IS NOT NULL
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, plus a small amount of representative data including some nulls.